# Label encoding without NAN Value

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to encode categorical variables without encoding the missing values. For the moment, I could not find the right solution, here is my code:

```py
# To define my df :
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['X', np.NaN, 'Z'], 'B': ['DB', 'AB', 'CA'], 'C': ['KH', 1, np.NaN]})
df :

A   B   C
0   X   DB  KH
1   NaN AB  1
2   Z   CA  NaN
# To encoding juste A variable :
Le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
target = Le.fit_transform(df['A'].astype(str))

# but this method also encodes NAN values

# then I tried another handle but it does not work:

Le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

# define the values of A not null and try again labelencoding:

Anotnull = df.loc[df['A'] != np.nan]
target = Le.fit_transform(Anotnull.astype(str))
```

The objective is to make labelencoding without touching the NaN values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is not technically label encoding "without touching the nans" but it will leave you with a label encoded data frame with the nans in their original place.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder


df_raw = pd.DataFrame({"feature1": ["a", "b", "c", np.nan, "e"],
                       "feature2": ["h", "i", np.nan, "k", "l"]})

# 1st possibility
df_temp = df_raw.astype("str").apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
df_final = df_temp.where(~df_raw.isna(), df_raw)

# 2nd possibility
df_temp = df_raw.astype("category").apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
df_final = df_temp.where(~df_raw.isna(), df_raw)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the first option works great for me! In my case, I need to store the encoding for each column, how can I best do that using this first method? Can I somehow save the LabelEncoder.classes_ in .apply?

Comment: You can always define an object, e.g. `le = LabelEncoder()`, and use that in the apply. The object should then contain everything that's been fitted in `fit_transform`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your quick suggestion! Unfortunately, it doesn't, since it still reinitializes the encoder each time, so I can't save the class encoding for individual columns. I solved it by writing an explicit loop, so bruteforcing ;) If you have a more elegant solution, I would be happy to test it! :)